# 投票を誤って行った場合の訂正は不可能？

Tags: サポート, 投票

iPhone で Stack Overflow を見ていた際に、スクロールしたときに誤って反対投票の▼を押してしまったようです。それに気付いたのが反対投票の1時間ほど後でした。
訂正しようとして PC でもう一度▼を押したのですが「あなたがこの回答に前回投票したのは 1時間前 です。この回答が編集されない限り、あなたの票は確定します」と表示されて訂正できません。

- 訂正可能な時間は何分ぐらいあるのでしょうか。
- 投票を自由に訂正できるようにすべきだとは思わないのですが、しかしなんらかの許諾（だれに？）を取れば訂正できる、などの許容手段があればありがたいです。

ご回答およびご検討よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 個人的な感覚に過ぎませんが；投票は2〜3分なら訂正が効く気がします。誤爆は私も経験があるので、1票くらいあまり気にしすぎないというのも一つの手(？)かと。

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かに気にしすぎないのも大事かと思うのですが、ただ賛成投票ならばともかく反対投票だったもので^^; さらに言えば、投票できたかどうかに関しても分かりづらいときがあるんですよね>_<

Comment: もしかして、iPhone上だと賛成/反対投票の▲/▼マークが表示されなかったりします？私が利用しているAndroidブラウザでも表示がおかしくて、自分だけかと思っていたのですがひょっとすると…（別メタ投稿にすべき話題ですがちょっとだけ気になったので）

Comment: iPhone の Safari/Chrome どちらでも白抜きの△/▽マークが表示され、タップすると▲/▼マークが表示されます。表示されないことは無さそうです。ただ、▲/▼の表示色がグレーなので目立ちにくいです。 PC での表示だと、元がグレーの▲/▼でクリックするとオレンジ色、時間が経つと黒色ですね（色変化をようやく理解しました）。できれば色は統一してほしいなぁと（ PC での黒/グレーの見分けも難しいです>_<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

初投票から５分以内その投票を変えることができます。

もし、投稿が編集された場合、投票を変えることができます。

詳しくは下記の英語の投票にあります：

[What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes)

投稿に編集するべき点があれば、推奨編集をして、承認後に投票を変えることになります。