# 常に、投票意思に沿った、投票状態に。

Tags: 機能の要求

特に、

一例として、
メタでの　討議では、
反論により　発癌信憑性が、
覆る　事が、
あり得ます。
"

しかし、

此を　拝見するに、
[投票を誤って行った場合の訂正は不可能？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1624/%e6%8a%95%e7%a5%a8%e3%82%92%e8%aa%a4%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e5%a0%b4%e5%90%88%e3%81%ae%e8%a8%82%e6%ad%a3%e3%81%af%e4%b8%8d%e5%8f%af%e8%83%bd)

変更は　許されない、
場合が　あるのですよね？
"

如何でしょう？

発言信憑性の　偽装が、
暴かれたなら。
"

連れて、

当然に　投票意思も、
変わりますが、

此の　点を、
実勢に　併せて、
変更可にしては　如何でしょう？

Answer (score 8):

反対です。たとえば、メタ回答やコメントなどでの議論によってメタ質問の内容の細部が分かり理解に齟齬があったと分かった場合、その齟齬を解消するためにメタ質問自体が編集されるはずですし、そうあるべきです。そして編集が起こった場合は投票の入れ直しができるようになります。したがって投票のやり直しを新しくできるようにする機能に必要性を感じませんでした。

Answer (score 4):

「覆る」とのことで、次の２パターンが考えられます。

- 過去に有益であり高評価されていたものが、その後、無益になった場合
- 過去に無益であり低評価されていたものが、その後、有益になった場合

前者については、無益になったとしても過去の事実は覆りませんので、評価を訂正する必要はないと判断します。よって、後者をメインに回答します。

---

Stack Overflowでは投票内容を変更できない点も含めてシステム設計されています。

まず、だれでも投票できるわけではありません。[プラス投票を行うにはアカウントを作り信頼度15を獲得](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)する必要があります。[マイナス投票は更に敷居が高く信頼度125](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)が必要です。具体的な人数でいうと、[現時点でプラス投票可能 2922 に対しマイナス投票可能 926](https://data.stackexchange.com/jame/query/1404129) と1/3程度に限られています。あくまでStack Overflowのシステムに慣れた人のみが投票できるようになっています。

更にマイナス投票にはペナルティがあります。回答に対してマイナス投票を行うと投票者自身の信頼度も下がります。ペナルティを負ってでもマイナス投票するか、必然的に慎重な判断が求められます。なお、質問に対するマイナス投票にはペナルティがありません。これは無益な質問を排除し、有益な質問のみに厳選するための仕組みです。

加えて回答や編集が行われるとトップに上がり閲覧者の目にとまるようになっています。不当に低く評価された投稿であれば、他の人が容易にプラス投票できます。
最後に、編集が行われれば、再投票可能になります。編集は投稿者本人の必要はなく、誰でも行えます。覆った事実を知ったものが編集を行えば、前述の通り他の人の目にとまり、尚且つ既投票者も投票内容を訂正可能になります。

---

ですので、無条件に再投票可能にする必要はありません。不当に低く評価されていたり覆った内容が記されていたり、その事実を知った人が編集を行えばいいだけです。

Answer (score 3):

nekketsuuu さんの回答や [既存の回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1625) と被る部分は省きますが、投票の変更に一定の制限があるのは、目にした文章への投票にある程度の慎重さを持ってもらうためだと私は思っています。

また、投票はあくまで第三者視点での評価に過ぎません。"質問と回答" という視点に立てば、例え評価が低い回答であっても質問者が納得すればベストアンサーになるし、逆に他者からの評価がいくら高くても質問者が求めるものと違えば別の回答が選ばれるケースもあります。

---

"発言信憑性の偽装" がいまいち分かりませんが、例えば誤読して投票してしまったという事であれば、時間が経つうちに別の第三者からの票が自然と集まっていくはずですし、それよりも「正当な評価をされるように、分かりやすい文章」な状態にされるべきだと思います。

そして、その「正当な評価」がされるよう、より伝わりやすい文章となるようにコメントで確認や改善を求めたり、一定の信用度を持つユーザーが直接投稿を編集できるような仕組みになっているのが当サイトの運用ルールです。